# 360 panorama using PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova

is there any way to run 360° panoramic with `phonegap`?

I tried to use ThreeJs, but it didn't work on my phone.

please reply I greatly need your help :(

thank you for advance.

Answer (score 1):

The best way  to use panoramic 360° in phonegap even in the web applications
I advise you to use  `Pano2VR` software.